# What sort of investment accounts are generally used for short term (not retirement) investing?

Tags: united-states, investing, financial-literacy

If accounts such as Roth IRA and 401(k) are designed for investing towards retirement, what sort of accounts do people generally use for short term investing, say 5-10 years?

Ideally there would be no penalty for early withdrawals. Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: Are you sure you are investing and not saving?  Your time period seems like it is on the bubble to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-retirement, non-tax-advantaged, savings/investment should be held in accounts with a level of risk and liquidity that is appropriate for the time horizon in which the funds will be needed.  So, depending on your comfort with investment risk:

- money that you need to access within the short term (however you define "short", perhaps 1 year or less) should be stored in transaction accounts (savings/checking at a bank), and
- money that's not needed until later (perhaps a horizon of greater than a year) can be used to purchase a variety of securities (Treasury bonds, Certificates of Deposit, Stocks, Bonds, etc.) through a non-tax-advantaged trading/brokerage account.

Almost all things that you're buying and selling through a trading/brokerage account (i.e. securities) are going to have some sort of penalty associated with the sale (early withdrawal penalties on CDs, short/long-term capital gains taxes, taxes on interest gains, etc.)

There are a few things that can be bought that are tax-advantaged, like certain types of savings bonds (e.g. municipal bonds), but these typically have rather poor rates of return.

So the short answer is that there's practically nothing that you can do to avoid penalties and taxes, short of making larger contributions to tax-advantaged accounts.  Though in most cases, this locks that money into longer-term (i.e. retirement) savings.

#### Side Note:

Thinking of 401(k)s and IRAs (of various flavors) as accounts is really the wrong perspective.  Permit me an analogy:  Your account (a transaction account (checking/savings), a Certificate of Deposit, a trading/brokerage account, etc.) is an entity in and of itself, kind of like individual human being.  IRAs/401(k)s are a legal arrangement that confers benefits and protections unto an account (tax-advantaged or tax-deferred growth, protection in bankruptcy/litigation, etc.) like a Kevlar vest protects a human being from injury when shot with a gun.  The 401(k)/IRA designation is a "protection" around an account.

Comment: @Chris:  I appreciate the edits, I agree that this formatting is better.

Answer (score 3):

You would use a regular trading account for such investments. You then pay tax on any capital gains.

There are a number of options for what to hold inside of such accounts, just as there are for Roth IRA and 401(k) accounts. Mutual funds, ETFs, stocks, bonds, GICs, CDs, etc. etc.

Comment: Is a brokerage account the same thing as a trading account?

Comment: @Ramin No, you cannot be farther from the truth. As a small time investor you need a trading account. When you become a billionaire and get a brokerage license then you can have a brokerage account. http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/brokerageaccount.asp

Comment: DC - In the US, it's common to call one's account in which they hold stock, their "brokerage account" and the company it's with, their "broker." The definition you link to supports my view. "An arrangement between an investor and a licensed brokerage firm." Why do you think otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

If the investments are for education, there can be specific accounts that exist like [529 Plans](http://www.sec.gov/investor/pubs/intro529.htm) for college as an example.  Thus, it is worth considering what purpose do you have that may be where special accounts could exist to facilitate that purpose.